# What is the real name of this tool? It's used to fix dupont lighter valves

Tags: repair, tools, gas

This tool is used to fix DuPont lighter but that is not its real name please you can help me a lot if you know the real name

[image: enter image description here**]

1. 

---

---

Comment: Is it a tool? Or a component a complete picture of the part would be helpful.

Comment: "lighter valve tool".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about home improvement

Answer (score 2):

It is a lighter valve extractor. It is threaded into and locked against the internal valve. Then the valve can be removed. If you have no instructions handy, there is a YT video showing a similar device at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wxTA7I9Ubo